# how to write a report into a file?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.3

I'm having problems with my code. I want to be able to write a report (which is a dictionary) into a file. I have this as my report:

```
{longs: ['stretched']
avglen: 4.419354838709677
freqs: {'could': 1, 'number': 1, 'half': 1, 'scorned': 1, 'come': 2, 'numbers': 1, 'rage': 1, 'metre': 1, 'termed': 1, 'heavenly': 1, 'touches': 1, 'i': 1, 'their': 1, 'poets': 1, 'a': 2, 'lies': 1, 'verse': 1, 'an': 1, 'as': 1, 'eyes': 1, 'touched': 1, 'knows': 1, 'tongue': 1, 'not': 1, 'yet': 1, 'filled': 1, 'heaven': 1, 'of': 4, 'earthly': 1, 'hides': 1, 'to': 2, 'stretched': 1, 'deserts': 1, 'this': 1, 'tomb': 1, 'write': 1, 'yellowed': 1, 'that': 1, 'alive': 1, 'some': 1, 'so': 1, 'such': 1, 'should': 2, 'like': 1, 'than': 1, 'antique': 1, 'yours': 1, 'but': 2, 'age': 2, 'less': 1, 'fresh': 1, 'time': 2, 'rhyme': 1, 'true': 1, 'neer': 1, 'all': 1, 'in': 4, 'live': 1, 'be': 2, 'your': 6, 'who': 1, 'truth': 1, 'child': 1, 'twice': 1, 'shows': 1, 'poet': 1, 'most': 1, 'life': 1, 'song': 1, 'will': 1, 'my': 3, 'if': 2, 'parts': 1, 'were': 2, 'you': 1, 'is': 1, 'papers': 1, 'it': 3, 'which': 1, 'rights': 1, 'with': 2, 'say': 1, 'old': 1, 'beauty': 1, 'high': 1, 'and': 5, 'would': 1, 'believe': 1, 'faces': 1, 'though': 1, 'men': 1, 'graces': 1, 'the': 2}
shorts: ['i', 'a']
count: 93
mosts: your}
```

and my code is:

```
def write_report(r, filename):    
input_file=open(filename, "w")
for k, v in r.items():
    line = '{}, {}'.format(k, v) 
    print(line, file=input_file)        
input_file.close()
return input_file
```

but if I name r as the report, it gives me syntax error.

I changed it to this code now:

```
def write_report(r, filename):
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    for k, v in r.items():
        f.write('{}, {}'.format(k, v) )
return f
```

but I get this error:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='sonnet_017.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

> > > 

Comment: That `report` is not a valid dictionary.. What is `your`? Dictionary items are separated by commas, which you don't have as well.

Comment: Generally python will tell you where the syntax error is, so post your error message will show where is the problem.

Comment: Your code indenting causes a SyntaxError. Fix the indentation first

Comment: when I fixed it I get this error every time I implement the code:<_io.TextIOWrapper name='sonnet_017.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>

Comment: That doesn't look like an error.  That looks like an instance of TextIOWrapper instead, or rather, what you're returning.

Comment: Please, add the code the current snippet is called from so we can get more context.

Answer (score 3):

This

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='sonnet_017.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>

is not an error message. It is the [repr](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#repr) of the return value of the function.  You have `return f` in your function, so it is returning the file object.

E.g.:

```
>>> f = open('junk.txt', 'w')
>>> f
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='junk.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Here's your function in action:

```
>>> r
{'bar': 12.345, 'foo': 'abc'}
>>> write_report(r, "junk.txt")
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='junk.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Now read the file back and see what we get:

```
>>> with open("junk.txt", "r") as f:
...     contents = f.read()
... 
>>> contents
'bar, 12.345foo, abc'
```

At a minimum, you might want to modify the `write_report` function to include a newline after writing each key/value pair:

```
    f.write('{}, {}\n'.format(k, v) )
```

Comment: so how do i check to make sure I wrote it into the file

Comment: Your code opens the file, writes to it and closes it.  If any of the file IO functions fail, they should raise an exception.   What do you want to check?

Comment: @user2976821 check the file you write it into. Or output it to the shell as you write it to the file.